# Implementing Infinite Scrolling in JSF by Primefaces, Waypoint and Masonry

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jquery-masonry, jquery-waypoints, primefaces-extensions

I am trying to implement infinite scrolling by using Primefaces with the assistance of jQuery Waypoint and Masonry API.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<f:view>
    <h:head>
        <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
        <h:outputScript name="js/global.js"/>
        <h:outputScript name="js/masonry.pkgd.js"/>
        <h:outputScript name="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/global.css" />                
        <title>Gallery</title>      
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form prependId="false">      
            <h:panelGroup id="galleryPanel" layout="block">
                <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="galleryContainer">
                        <ui:repeat id="gallery" value="#{galleryController.images}"  var="image">
                            <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="item">
                                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="demo/#{image}.jpg" />
                            </h:panelGroup>                 
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </h:panelGroup>                                     
                </p:outputPanel>                
                <pe:waypoint id="waypoint" widgetVar="waypointWidget" offset="function(){return $.waypoints('viewportHeight') - $(this).outerHeight()}">
                    <pe:javascript event="reached" execute="handleLoadStart(ext);"/>  
                </pe:waypoint>
                <h:outputScript target="body">
                    var layout = function(){
                        var container = $('.galleryContainer');
                        $(container).imagesLoaded(function(){
                            $(container).masonry({
                                itemSelector : '.item',
                                columnWidth : 240
                            });
                        });
                    };

                    var handleLoadStart = function(ext) {
                        if (ext.direction == "down") { 
                            PF('waypointWidget').remove();                          
                            moreMedia();
                        }
                    };

                    var handleLoadStop = function(){
                        layout();
                        PF('waypointWidget').register();                         
                    };                  

                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        layout();
                    });
                </h:outputScript>               
                <p:remoteCommand name="moreMedia" update="gallery" actionListener="#{galleryController.loadMore}" oncomplete="handleLoadStop()"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

The Managed Bean is:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

@ManagedBean(name="galleryController")
@ViewScoped
public class GalleryController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 563439107531288284L;

    private List<String> images;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        images = new ArrayList<>();     
        IntStream.range(1, 16).forEach(i->images.add(new String("image" + i)));     
    }

    public void loadMore(ActionEvent event){
        IntStream.range(1, 16).forEach(i->images.add(new String("image" + i))); 
    }

    public List<String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(List<String> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }    
}
```

It is partially working, as it has issues.

The major issue is, as I am adding new images to the existing image list, the `ui:repeat` is rendering completely. I don't want to do this. Because by this way the existing images also get loaded. Modern browser like FF or Chome caches images, so it would not be a problem for them, but in the browser like IE I can see in Network console that it is sending GET to fetch those images. From the performance perspective the images which has already been loaded should not get fetched, only the newly added images.

But I don't know how can I make it in JSF!

Also as a side effect, the Masonry is not working as desired. Every time when the `onComplete` of `p:remoteCommand` is triggering the `layout()` method, the scrollbar is getting set to the top. From the functional perspective it should stay at that location from where the Waypoint triggered the next load.

Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces Extensions has pe:fluidGrid based on Masonry by the way. Check the showcase http://primeext.mooo.com:8080/primeext-showcase/views/fluidGrid.jsf

Answer (score 0):

You do not update the ui:repeat anymore after initial load.  Use a temporary data storage such as h:inputHidden  to hold data returned and formatted by the the managed and then use JavaScript to move data from h:inputHidden  to Masonry.  In Masonry use the following to append data:

```
$container.masonry( "appended", html, true );
```

where html is the data of  h:inputHidden

If you want you can visit this the blog below for details.  It does not use PrimeFaces nor WayPoints but how Masonry is updated is similar to what wanted to do.

http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/code-blogs/1699/how-to-use-and-append-data-to-masonry-in-responsive-jquerymobile-with-jsf-2-and-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you need an infinite list using

```
<ul>
   <li>item 1</li>
   <li>item 2</li>
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

The idea is to create a composite component called list.xhml for instance with an attribute index.
That component could load a page of 10 elements for example.
When you scroll, load that component with JQuery ajax and add it to the dom.